# Send SMS only once from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I saw Commonwares LocationPoller demo here
github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/

Here in the `LocationReceiver` I am checking whether the location is in specified area or not.
If it is not in that area I send an text message(SMS) to phone number.

But it is sendind text messages(SMS) continuously as it receives new location at every specific interval. So I defined a class varible `flag`=0 (initally)

```
            public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                int flag=0;
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            ............


            if( flag==0)    //center of campus 
                      {
                          checkArea(loc,"500","22.599669","72.820473","5556","Your ward is out of College campus");
                          Toast.makeText(context, "You Have Moved out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                          flag=1;
                      }
                }
            }
```

But it is not working, it still sends SMS continuously.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Save a unix timestamp when you send the message using SharedPreferences so the next time the broadcast is fired you check for the existance of said timestamp. You'd only send the message if the timestamp does not exist or it is old enough (Actual time - saved timestamp >= Some Threshshold you define), updating or creating the timestamp when you send the message.

Comment: In `MyPreference` extends `PreferenceActivity` how do I add preference without use of XML like `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); `      Since its the only preference

Comment: SharedPreferences != PrefenceActivity. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Comment: @Machinaruis Thanks...But how do I see if the Timestamp exists or not >?

Comment: Long curTS1=System.currentTimeMillis();
       String TS=prefs.getString("sms",curTS1.toString());
      
       
       if(checkArea(loc,sRad,sCLat,sCLon,MobNo,TxtMsg) )
       {
        if(curTS1==Long.parseLong(TS) && curTS1-Long.parseLong(TS)>3600000)
        {             will this work ?

Comment: i'd rather check for the timestamp differences before checking the locations, as it's easier and most probable that not enough time has passed, you'd save computations and therefore battery

Answer (score 1):

You can use persistence storage to store state and every time you receive notification check with your storage if you have to send SMS or not.